# AsynceTask Image Crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Well I am a begginer and I would be happy for some help.

So when you press the button,the Image should load from the website the image and show it as an

ImageView.

I try to run this code,but everytime I press the button to show the image,the app crash.

Thank you:)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView mImageView;

    public void clickButton(View view){

        Log.d("Proccess" , "Button pressed");
        ImageDownloader myTask = new ImageDownloader();
        Bitmap myImage;

        try {
            myImage = myTask.execute("https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/410/media/images/47104000/jpg/_47104670_homer_226other.jpg").get();
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(myImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.mImageView);

    }

    public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask< String,Void, Bitmap > {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                connection.connect();

                InputStream myStream = connection.getInputStream();

                Bitmap in = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(myStream);


                return in;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: Get rid of `get()`. Even better, get rid of the deprecated `AsyncTask` and use an image-loading library like Glide or Picasso, as they will handle loading the image on a background thread for you.